# Python Pandas DataFrame: unorderable types: str() > int()

Tags: python, string, pandas, int

I have downloaded the file mentioned in book "Python for Data Analysis" and was going through the example FEC database mentioned in page 278. I get the following Type error when I ran the command. My versions: Python 3.4; Pandas: 0.14.0. OS: Windows 8

```
>>> fec=pd.read_csv('c:\python\P00000001-ALL.csv')
>>> (fec.contb_receipt_amt > 0).value_counts()
>>> TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

But it is not just this dataset. Any dataset that I am working with have similar problem. Int(Number) data types are being imported as objects like anything else and when run any comparison with numbers(>0) on them I get the above error. What is the work around? I tried importing with dtype option, which throws an error that says int64 or Float64 is not available. I am sure there is a right way of doing. How to load the data frame with the right data types.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well you've already deduced that comparing a string to an int won't work, it should've deduced the dtypes from the call to `read_csv` which is a bit odd, what happens if you convert the type: `fec.contb_receipt_amt = fec.contb_receipt_amt.astype(np.float64)` does it work then

Comment: I notice you are not escaping your slashes in the path, is this loading correctly? try `fec=pd.read_csv(r'c:\python\P00000001-ALL.csv')`

Comment: I just tested your code against the github repos: https://github.com/pydata/pydata-book/tree/master/ch09 and it worked fine so I don't know what your problem is, can you post a link to your data so I can have a look

Comment: @EdChum Goot point, but shouldn't make any difference, as neither `\p` not `\P` are valid escape sequences and thus will be taken as they are.

Comment: Ed and team, Thank you very much for your responses. I originally got the following error when I first loaded. "DtypeWarning: Columns (6,11,12) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False."                                 But I ignored since my amount column is the 9th column and the warning was about other columns. I executed the following command as suggested             >>> fec.contb_receipt_amt = fec.contb_receipt_amt.astype(np.float64) and I got the following error..                                     ValueError: could not convert string to float: '28-JUN-12'

Comment: I tried the following(by only taking the columns I need from the file. As there seems to be mixed data types those 3 columns.) and it sort of worked out for me for now.                                  >>> fec = pd.read_csv(r'c:\Python\P00000001-ALL.csv', usecols=(2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10)) and now the 
>> (fec.contb_receipt_amt>0).value_counts() doesn't error out and gives the following result.                                            True     5291868
False      58069
dtype: int64

Comment: What surprises me is why '28-JUN-12' was in the contb_receipt_amt column when I loaded the entire file first time?                                                                 The file is downloaded from here... http://www.fec.gov/disclosurep/PDownload.do If you can throw some light on that, it would be great.                                        Sorry I didn't know how to post a long message, so I did in three messages.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error for some not identical dates. I solved it using a type change first.

Try :

```
fec[[contb_receipt_amt]] = fec[[contb_receipt_amt]].astype(str)
```

Then try again the count.